# Get data from multiple json array in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have JSON data like this and I want to get those values with the same sample_time I tried Jason.parse() but it does not work and I got an error saying "Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1"

```
[
    {
        "group_name": "exampele",
        "group_id": 11,
        "data_models": [
            {
                "data_model": "min",
                "data_model_id": 43,
                "values": [
                    {
                        "sender_id": 21,
                        "sender_phone_number": "+123456",
                        "sample_time": 1559930895,
                        "value": "58", //get this data
                        "created_at": "2019-06-07T18:13:15.773Z",
                        "updated_at": "2019-06-07T18:13:15.778Z"
                    },
                    {
                        "sender_id": 21,
                        "sender_phone_number": "+123456",
                        "sample_time": 1559930896,
                        "value": "58",
                        "created_at": "2019-06-07T18:13:15.716Z",
                        "updated_at": "2019-06-07T18:13:15.720Z"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "data_model": "max",
                "data_model_id": 44,
                "values": [
                    {
                        "sender_id": 21,
                        "sender_phone_number": "+123456",
                        "sample_time": 1559930895,
                        "value": "85",//get this data too
                        "created_at": "2019-06-07T18:13:15.785Z",
                        "updated_at": "2019-06-07T18:13:15.790Z"
                    },
                    {
                        "sender_id": 21,
                        "sender_phone_number": "+123456",
                        "sample_time": 1559930896,
                        "value": "85",
                        "created_at": "2019-06-07T18:13:15.772Z",
                        "updated_at": "2019-06-07T18:13:15.776Z"
                    }  
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I want get those commended values with javascript how can i do that.

Comment: This question is very unclear. What do you mean by "get those values with the same sample_time"? What would be the expected output? Please show actual code.

Comment: We can't help you with code we can't see. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)). Also, note that JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Comment: There is an extra comma at the end of the `data_models` array. If this is real JSON and not Javascript it is not allowed.

Comment: _"Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1"_ - Then it's not JSON but already an object

Comment: Your question isn't clear. 
Retrieving values from object, you need to loop through the object with key-value pairs. You can use Object.entries to get value easily.

Comment: Sounds like you already have an object and can use it directly without parsing. The data is only JSON when it's still a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const json = [
    {
        "group_name": "exampele",
        "group_id": 11,
        "data_models": [
            {
                "data_model": "min",
                "data_model_id": 43,
                "values": [
                    {
                        "sender_id": 21,
                        "sender_phone_number": "+123456",
                        "sample_time": 1559930895,
                        "value": "58",
                        "created_at": "2019-06-07T18:13:15.773Z",
                        "updated_at": "2019-06-07T18:13:15.778Z"
                    },
                    {
                        "sender_id": 21,
                        "sender_phone_number": "+123456",
                        "sample_time": 1559930896,
                        "value": "58",
                        "created_at": "2019-06-07T18:13:15.716Z",
                        "updated_at": "2019-06-07T18:13:15.720Z"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "data_model": "max",
                "data_model_id": 44,
                "values": [
                    {
                        "sender_id": 21,
                        "sender_phone_number": "+123456",
                        "sample_time": 1559930895,
                        "value": "85",
                        "created_at": "2019-06-07T18:13:15.785Z",
                        "updated_at": "2019-06-07T18:13:15.790Z"
                    },
                    {
                        "sender_id": 21,
                        "sender_phone_number": "+123456",
                        "sample_time": 1559930896,
                        "value": "85",
                        "created_at": "2019-06-07T18:13:15.772Z",
                        "updated_at": "2019-06-07T18:13:15.776Z"
                    }  
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
];
const sample = json[0]['data_models'][0]['values'][0]['value'];
console.log(sample);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Now if that json has already been parse then you just need to iterate to each item like the below.

```
const sample = json[0]['data_models'][0]['values'][0]['value'];
```

You can see that there are index = 0 which needs to be on a loop so you can get all the values dynamically.